# audio or video play for some sec then need to stop playing

Tags: php, jquery

I need to play video/ Audio play for some sec then need to stop playing,
and after payment they can watch full video/ Audio,

My problem is: 
1. How to stop video/ Audio by its class or ID after 15 sec.

Comment: If you only stop it, you still have send the complete content and people can watch it. What you need is a separate small file (15secs) and at the end you show your payment information and the full link

Comment: yes, that is possible, Can u also guide me how I use payment gateways after this,
Sorry I am very new to this :)
Please send me link from where I can buy or cll its API

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How do you stream the video? Flash? HTML5? In any case, sounds like you should have 2 available streams for each video: preview and full, and stream each accordingly.